# Adding temporary list into another list, losing list data

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

First program with Python... I am trying to rearrange `.xyz` data from 3 columns (xyz) into a `list`, that has all `x` values in a `list` that have the same `z` value.

```
    coordinates = []
    zListTemp = []
    zSetTemp = []
    zList = []
```

Pull in data from `.xyz` file into `coordinates`.

```
    xyz = open("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\testXYZ01.xyz")

    for line in xyz:
        x,y,z = line.split()
        coordinates.append([float(x), float(y), float(z)])
    xyz.close()
```

Take all the `z`s from `coordinates` and put into `zSet`, because I want to put all unique `x`s into a list based on the different `z`s.

```
    for index0, item0 in enumerate(coordinates):
        for index1, item1 in enumerate(coordinates[index0]):
            if index1 == 2:
                zSetTemp.append(item1)
    zSet = list(set(zSetTemp))
    zSet.sort()

    print "zSet:", zSet

    print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

I believe this is where my issue is.
Take all `x`s that have the same `z` and append them into `zListTemp`. Add `zListTemp` to `zList`, `del` `zListTemp` for next `for`. At the end of this, each `list` within `zList` should be the temporary data from the previous `zListTemp`s.

```
    for iRange in range(len(zSet)):
        for i in (coordinates):
            if i[2] == zSet[iRange]:
                zListTemp.append(i[0])
        print zListTemp
        #zList.append(zListTemp)
        zList += [zListTemp]
        print zList
        del zListTemp[:]
        print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"


    print "list 1", zList[0]
    print "list 2", zList[1]
    print "zlist len", len(zList)
```

At the end I end up with empty lists in `zList`. Is the `zList` losing the `zListTemp` data because I delete the `zListTemp` data? My output:

```
    zSet: [0.00485, 0.02425]
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [35352.0, 35344.0, ..., 35396.0, 35428.0]
    [[35352.0, 35344.0, ..., 35396.0, 35428.0]]
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [35300.0, 35300.0, ..., 35444.0, 35460.0]
    [[35300.0, 35300.0, ..., 35412.0, 35444.0, 35460.0], [35300.0, 35300.0, ..., 35444.0, 35460.0]]
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    list 1 []
    list 2 []
    zlist len 2
    [Finished in 0.5s]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post a sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding `[zListTemp]` to `zList`, and then you modify `zListTemp`.

Your zList contains multiple references to the same zListTemp object. Once you modify it, zList seems to change as well. You modify zListTemp when you add values to it, or when you clear it with `del zListTemp[:]` .

You can fix it by not changing the temporary list but rather by using a new list every time. You do that by replacing the del line with:

```
zListTemp = []   # zListTemp now references a new empty list
```

That said, your code is rather long, and unnecessarily so. For instance, to get all the Z's from your coordinate list you can use:

```
all_zs = [c[2] for c in coordinates]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This makes sense. I will be able to let you know in a few days if it works.